# Crash when using indexPath.row in a modalViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, modalviewcontroller, nsindexpath

I've a problem with indexPath.row, when I try to access this variable my app crashes and I get no errors on the console :(

the code is this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath); //works fine
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row); //crash
}
```

and I'm using it inside a ModalViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.row);
```

This is because, indexpath.row is an integer and you have to use the %d .